# Module Name dynamic at sdist

Tags: python, setup.py

How Can I achieve the following behave in python? pythonic way.

Given my module:

```
mymodule
├── __init__.py
├── resources
│   └── application.conf
├── mymodulecodes.py
```

when I create the

```
 NAME=xxx python setup.py sdist
```

I've have a mymodule-1.0.0.tar.gz that's install mymodule_xxx.

so that I could

```
import mymodule_xxx.mymodulecodes
```

any idea?

Comment: If you're building a binary dist (egg or wheel), the solution would be a simple remapping of package names via `package_dir`. This won't work for source dists though, as there is no packaging step. you would need to override the `sdist` command that creates a separate copy of the `mymodule` package under a different name, uses it instead of `mymodule` when generating the list of included files and cleans it up afterwards.